# Using 64 bit integer iterator for 32 bit address space?

Tags: c, memory, integer, compiler-warnings

I'm writing some code (that runs on an FPGA) that writes a pattern to a block of memory specified by it's base address and highest address. The data width is 64 bits and the address space is 32 bits. On my system longs are 32 bits and long longs are 64 bits. The code looks something like this:

```
unsigned long base_addr = 0xC0000000;
unsigned long high_addr = 0xFFFFFFFF;
unsigned long long i;

for(i = base_addr; i <= high_addr; i += 4){
    *((unsigned long *) i) = some_pattern; 
}
```

Everything works fine but I get a "cast to pointer from integer of different size" warning from the compiler. If I use a 32 bit iterator variable the code loops infinitely since the iterator hits 0xFFFFFFFC and then overflows back to 0 again.

Is there a better way to do this? I know there are lots of ways to use a 32 bit iterator without problems (detect/predict the overflow, subtract 3 from the high_addr) but I think this code is the simplest and most readable. Is it considered bad style to write code with known compiler errors?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you declaring `i` as `unsigned long long`? What is the point of that?

As you said yourself, addresses on your platform are 32 bit. Declare `i` as `unsigned long`, just like `base_addr` and `high_addr`. The warning should disappear.

Meanwhile, what is the meaning of "data width is 64 bits"? If the data (and the pattern) is actually 64 bits, then you should be doing

```
for (i = base_addr; i <= high_addr; i += 8){ /* or i += sizeof(unsigned long long) */
    *((unsigned long long *) i) = some_pattern; 
}
```

Also, note that if, for example, `i` becomes equal to `high_addr` during iterations, your cycle body will still execute, accessing 7 extra bytes beyond `high_addr`. Was that the intent?

Answer (score 2):

My idea of a better way to do it:

```
unsigned long long *base_addr = (unsigned long long *)0xC0000000;
unsigned long long *high_addr = (unsigned long long *)0xFFFFFFFF;
unsigned long long *i;

for (i = base_addr; i < high_addr; ++i) {
    *i = some_pattern;
}
```

May need to be careful of pointer (i) wrap-around, by aborting the for loop if `i < base_addr` too.